# Procedure "complexa"

Tags: sql

Olá.

Estou aprendendo procedures e estou com uma dúvida:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `atualiza_telefone` (IN telefone INT)
BEGIN  

IF (telefone IS NULL) THEN
SELECT * FROM cliente; 

ELSE UPDATE cliente
SET telefone = "4444-4444"
WHERE seg_nome = 'Binatti';
END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Eu gostaria de, caso o telefone for atualizado, colocar para fazer um `SELECT * FROM cliente`, para mostrar que o telefone foi atualizado.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Grato!

Comment: Mais para que serviria seu select? você vai mostrar onde que foi alterado ?

Comment: Serviria para mostrar a  tabela com os novos valores.

Comment: OK, Isso você vai fazer através de uma aplicação?  só é esse parâmetro que a proc tem? se for você não precisa do `IF (telefone IS NULL) THEN
SELECT * FROM cliente; ` para você chama a proc você tem que passar o parâmetro dessa forma nunca será `IS NULL`

Comment: O `if` eu coloquei apenas para entender como funcionava. Tentei jogar o máximo de coisas possíveis. Era só pra ver como reagiria.

Comment: Vamos lá, Em qual situação você chamaria uma `PROCEDURE` que faz atualização se não para atualizar os dados. Se você tem uma aplicação que faz atualização do seu **cliente**, por exemplo, você provavelmente já tem os dados dele no seu formulário de alteração, quando você chamar sua Proc você informa o que esta sendo alterado. Então para que você retornaria o que foi alterado se você já tem na sua aplicação?

Comment: Certo, eu entendi o que você quis dizer.
Porém, eu queria saber como faço para colocar pra ele rodar o `select` logo após ter atualizado os dados. 
Queria entender essa parada de duas instruções em uma só clausulá, entende?
Não tiro sua razão de ser "desnecessário", mas eu queria saber como funciona.

Comment: Bom, pelo padrão

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do IF, logo depois do WHERE, eu tentaria o seguinte:

IF (telefone IS NOT NULL) THEN

```
    UPDATE cliente
    SET telefone = "4444-4444"
    WHERE seg_nome = 'Binatti;
    SELECT * FROM CLIENTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Vou por aqui não exatamente como uma resposta, mas pela formatação.

Bom, pelo padrão *PROCEDURES* não deveriam retornam valores, mas se você for fazer isso tem que por o select na instrução final.

Veja se assim funciona.

Agora se sua intenção é;

> Queria entender essa parada de duas instruções em uma só clausulá,
>   entende?

É preciso que você explique melhor o que quer.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `atualiza_telefone` (IN telefone INT)
BEGIN  

    IF (telefone IS NOT NULL) THEN

        UPDATE cliente
        SET telefone = "4444-4444"
        WHERE seg_nome = 'Binatti';

    ELSE 

        SELECT * FROM cliente; 

    END IF;


END $$

DELIMITER ;
```